# awk variable assignment don't work under switch/case

Tags: awk

I am writing a script that can create proxy rule from a csv file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -F', ' '
  function head (soft, keyword) {
    if (soft == "clash") {
      switch (keyword) {
        case "HOST":
          rule_head = "- DOMAIN";
          break;
        case "KEYWORD":
          rule_head = "- DOMAIN-KEYWORD";
          break;
        case "SUFFIX":
          rule_head = "- DOMAIN-SUFFIX";
          break;
        case "IP-CIDR":
          rule_head = "- IP-CIDR";
          break;
      }
    } else
    if (soft == "quant") {
      switch (keyword) {
        case "HOST":
          rule_head = "HOST";
          break;
        case "KEYWORD":
          rule_head = "HOST-KEYWORD";
          break;
        case "SUFFIX":
          rule_head = "HOST-SUFFIX";
          break;
        case "IP-CIDR":
          rule_head = "IP-CIDR";
          break;
      }
    }
    ruturn rule_head;
  }

  function tail (soft, keyword) {
    if (soft == "clash") {
      switch (keyword) {
        case "REJECT":
          rule_tail = "REJECT";
          break;
        case "DIRECT":
          rule_tail = "DIRECT";
          break;
        case "jp_proxy":
          rule_tail = "Japan_Tokyo";
          break;
        case "us_proxy":
          rule_tail = "USA_Oregon";
          break;
        case "kr_proxy":
          rule_tail = "Korea_Seoul";
          break;
      }
    } else
    if (soft == "quant") {
      switch (keyword) {
        case "REJECT":
          rule_tail = "REJECT";
          break;
        case "DIRECT":
          rule_tail = "DIRECT,no-resolve";
          break;
        case "jp_proxy":
          rule_tail = "Japan - Tokyo";
          break;
        case "us_proxy":
          rule_tail = "USA - Oregon";
          break;
        case "kr_proxy":
          rule_tail = "Korea - Seoul";
          break;
      }
    }
    return rule_tail;
  }

  {
    if (NR>2) {
      printf "%s,%s,%s\n", head(clash, $2), $3 ,tail(clash, $4);
    }
  }
' Resources/exception.csv
```

and the file **Resources/exception.csv**

```
# group, type, basis, action, comment

china_list, KEYWORD, 360buy, DIRECT, No_comment
china_list, KEYWORD, baidu, DIRECT, No_comment
china_list, KEYWORD, bdstatic, DIRECT, No_comment
china_list, KEYWORD, bcebos, DIRECT, No_comment
proxy_list, KEYWORD, fbcdn, us_proxy, No_comment
proxy_list, KEYWORD, twitter, us_proxy, No_comment
proxy_list, KEYWORD, twimg, us_proxy, No_comment
```

and the shell output is

```
,360buy,
,baidu,
,bdstatic,
,bcebos,
,fbcdn,
,twitter,
,twimg,
```

The *rule_head* and *rule_tail* seems not working at all, I already tried to print the keyword inside *function head or tail > if* before *switch/case*, it can print the keyword correctly.

But when I tried to print the *rule_head or rule_tail* after the switch/case, it output noting.

Comment: Could you please mention expected output in your post too?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 My expected output, example for the last line from the *exception.csv* should be `- DOMAIN-KEYWORD,twimg,USA_Oregon`.

Comment: You need to quote `"clash"` in each of `head(clash, $2), $3 ,tail(clash, $4)`

Comment: You have a typo `ruturn rule_head`

Comment: @JoshuaLee, could you please try doing `head("clash", $2)`, AND `tail("clash", $4)` and let me know then?

Comment: @flu I was trying the different between return and print. This issue make me blurred a lot.

Comment: @jas @RavinderSingh13 What is the different between `head("clash", $2)` and `head(clash, $2)`, why `head(clash, $2)` will not work, awk treat `clash` as a variable?

Comment: @JoshuaLee, yes `"clash"` means string is being passed and `clash` means you are passing a variable named `clash`. I have mentioned in my answer both kind of solutions 1st- with passing string, 2nd- by using variable and pasing it in function.

Comment: @JoshuaLee. mentioning anything insdide `"` double quotes means we are mentioniong value, if you want to have a variable and assign value to it use `var="bla"` or you want to pass directly anything without variable any value then use `print "bla"` for example I am mentioning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try changing either(I am driving so haven't test it but should work if your code is not having any syntax issues)

`head(clash, $2), $3 ,tail(clash, $4);` ----> `head("clash", $2), $3 ,tail("clash", $4);`.

OR you could create a variable with `awk -v value="clash"` to keep it in variable format only. Then mention:

```
head(value, $2), $3 ,tail(value, $4);
```

@JoshuaLee. mentioning anything inside `"` double quotes means we are mentioniong value, if you want to have a variable and assign value to it use `var="bla"` or you want to pass directly anything without variable any value then use print `"bla"` for example I am mentioning here.

Comment: @Joshua, for completeness, in awk when you use an uninitialized variable, awk will handle it as an empty string or the number zero, depending on the context.